# Can't Dynamically Import in Next

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js, es6-modules, commonjs

I am trying to dynamically import a rich text editor (CKEditor 4), so that the loading of that (heavy) library doesn't slow down my initial page load.  To this end, I have the following component:

```
const LazyCKEditor4 = dynamic(
  async () => (await import('ckeditor4-react')).CKEditor
);
```

The problem is, when I build my project, that line becomes:

```
    , C = l(async()=>(await t.e(504).then(t.bind(t, 9504))).CKEditor, {
      loadableGenerated: {
          webpack: ()=>[require.resolveWeak("ckeditor4-react")]
      }
```

... which results in an error: `ReferenceError: require is not defined`.  The error makes sense (I'm using ES Modules, not CommonJS, so there *shouldn't* be a `require` function) ... but I can't figure out why Next/Webpack is generating code with a `require`.

Iterestingly enough, on my local machine this doesn't happen ... even though it's using the same code, same `package.json` (and thus same libraries), same database, etc.

Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong to make Next (via Webpack) convert my dynamic `import` into a `require` (but only in production)?

Comment: I have never seen the `.CKEditor`. Is that to import a [named module](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-named-exports)?

Comment: @YoussoufOumar Yes, that's accessing a named export on the namespace object that the `import()` promise fulfills with